# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs inside JHipster page - how to?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jhipster

I have a JHipster generated html page. Need Tabs, and this code is the basic example Bootstrap provide:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <p>Section A content…</p>
     </div>
    <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p>Section B content…</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks fine on first rendering, but when you click a tab it takes you to the home page. Presumably this means it cant find the href="#sectionB", for example.

Guess: The page URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/#/mypagename
```

so the # is throwing out the reference?

Have tried everything I can think of.

Suggestions?

Comment: I still don't have an answer to this. If someone can think of some de-bugging approach that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but thought I'd record an answer, since I just ran into this same problem.
I followed the instructions [here.](http://www.grobmeier.de/bootstrap-tabs-with-angular-js-25112012.html)

Basically, normal href's don't work in Angular, you need to use the javascript code provided on the Bootstrap site.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Of course, this is Angular so you should write a directive for UI manipulations.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('showtab',
    function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(element).tab('show');
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Then, in your html,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a showtab="" href="#tabone">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a showtab="" href="#tabtwo">Tab Two</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabone">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabtwo">...</div>
</div>
```

The showtab directive will enable the javascript necessary to switch tabs.

Note: you will need bootstrap.js included in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Jhispter with angularjs uses https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ since the use of bootstrap with angular is not fully compatible, so the way you create tabs is like this:

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Justified">Justified content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Long Justified">Labeled Justified</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```